# RandomizedSearchCV independently on models in an ensemble

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Suppose I construct an ensemble of two estimators, where each estimator runs its own parameter search:

Imports and regression dataset:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingRegressor, StackingRegressor, RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

X, y = make_regression()
```

Define two self-tuning estimators, and ensemble them:

```
rf_param_dist = dict(n_estimators=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
rf_searcher = RandomizedSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(), rf_param_dist, n_iter=5, cv=3)

dt_param_dist = dict(max_depth=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
dt_searcher = RandomizedSearchCV(DecisionTreeRegressor(), dt_param_dist, n_iter=5, cv=3)

ensemble = StackingRegressor(
    [ ('rf', rf_searcher), ('dt', dt_searcher) ]
).fit(X, y)
```

My questions are about how `sklearn` handles the fitting of `ensemble`.

Q1) We have two unfitted estimators in parallel, and both need to be fitted before `ensemble.predict(...)` would work. But we can't fit any of the estimators without first getting a prediction from the ensemble. How does `sklearn` handle this circular dependency?

Q2) Since we have two estimators running independent tuning, does each estimator make the false assumption that the parameters of the other estimator are fixed? So we end up with a poorly-defined optimisation problem.

---

For reference, I think the correct way to jointly optimise the models of an ensemble would be to define a single CV that searches over all parameters jointly, shown below. But my questions are about how `sklearn` handles the special case described earlier.

```
#Joint optimisation
ensemble = VotingRegressor(
    [ ('rf', RandomForestRegressor()), ('dt', DecisionTreeRegressor()) ]
)

jointsearch_param_dist = dict(
    rf__n_estimators=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    dt__max_depth=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
)

ensemble_jointsearch = RandomizedSearchCV(ensemble, jointsearch_param_dist)
```

Comment: probably better to stick to either StackingRegressor or VotingRegressor in your examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1) We have two unfitted estimators in parallel, and both need to be fitted before ensemble.predict(...) would work. **But we can't fit any of the estimators without first getting a prediction from the ensemble.** How does sklearn handle this circular dependency?

The sentence I've emphasized is incorrect.  In this approach, the individual estimators are tuned for their own performance; the tuning doesn't know or care that eventually it will get used in an ensemble.  *After* the optimal hyperparameters are found, the resulting models get ensembled.

For `VotingRegressor` that's basically it.  For `StackingRegressor` there's a nested cross-validation happening, so the preceding paragraph is slightly wrong.  The hyperparameter tuning happens on every fold from the stacking fitting procedure, with the selected model making predictions on the held out fold to make the training set for the meta-estimator.  So in fact, different hyperparameters may be selected for each such split.  The final ensemble uses yet another version of the model, tuned on the entire training set.

> Q2) Since we have two estimators running independent tuning, does each estimator make the false assumption that the parameters of the other estimator are fixed? So we end up with a poorly-defined optimisation problem.

Given the above, this is moot: the two estimators don't know that the other even exists, let alone what hyperparameters will be selected for it.  But you are right that there's a difference with your final approach.

> For reference, I think the correct way to jointly optimise the models of an ensemble would be to define a single CV that searches over all parameters jointly, shown below. But my questions are about how sklearn handles the special case described earlier.

Both methods are "correct", it just depends on how much of the hyperparameter space you want to search.  The former assumes that the optimal ensemble arises from optimal individual models, whereas the latter allows for an ensemble that performs better using suboptimal base models.  The latter is more likely to be true, but is more computationally costly, and the former may or may not perform reasonably well in comparison.  (And maybe the latter can even overfit more on your training set given its greater capacity.)

Comment: Really informative, thank you. I am not clear on the first point - "*After* the optimal hyperparameters are found, the resulting models get ensembled.". To tune an individual estimator requires that a score can be computed downstream from that estimator. Suppose the search tries a hyperparameter for an estimator and makes a prediction - the prediction will first need to pass through the unfitted ensembling step before it can be scored against the supplied target. I've only supplied the target at the ensemble's output. Propagating an input thru an unfitted ensembling step should raise an error.

Comment: @user3128 The target gets passed to the base estimators for fitting them, and the tuning is done against the scoring method provided, on that target.  (The target being passed down is necessary to fit the estimators at all, even without hyperparameter tuning.)